# Como habilito meu iPhone para usar em testes pelo xCode?

Tags: xcode

Preciso utilizar meu smartphone para testar um APP, mas não sei como habilitar ele no xCode.

-Já tenho conta de desenvolvedor;

-Já cadastrei ele como um device em  - https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/

Como proceder para poder utilizar ele no xCode?

-xCode 7.3.1

-iPhone6s

-IOS 10.0.2

Comment: Ele reconhece, mas me da essa mensagem de erro "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualize o XCode instalando a versão mais recente pois o 7.x não suporta o iOS10. Há como fazer gambiarras para poder usar mas não é recomendável. Se não tiver um motivo específico para continuar com o XCode 7, instale a versão 8.